# How to make submenus?

Tags: python, yowsup

I would like a help to make submenus, from the menu number "1". I tried using the code below but it did not work.

Here is my code:

```
@signals.message_received.connect
def handle(message):
    # Main menu
    if message.command == "Olá":
        menuPrincipal(message)
    # 1 - Budgeting
    elif message.command == "1":
        orcamentos(message)
    # 2 - Track an order already in progress
    elif message.command == "2":
        pedidoAndamento(message)
    # 3 - Change the date, time or location of the event
    elif message.command == "3":
        alterarPedido(message)
    # 4 - Special Offers
    elif message.command == "4":
        promocoes(message)
    # 5 - Speak to a representative
    elif message.command == "5":
        chamarRepresentante(message)
```

Below is the `orcamentos()` function that I would like to put as a submenu:

```
def orcamentos(message):
    mac.send_message(txtOrcamentos, message.conversation)
        # 1 Party kit
    if message.command == "1":
        partyKit(message)
        # 2 Confectionery cake
    elif message.command == "2":
        confCake(message)
        # 3 Salty pie
    elif message.command == "3":
        saltPie(message)
        # 4 Cupcakes
    elif message.command == "4":
        cupcakes(message)
        # 5 Sweets
    elif message.command == "5":
        sweets(message)
        # 6 Salty
    elif message.command == "6":
        salty(message)
```

Comment: What user interface library are you using?

Comment: A library that connects via whatstapp, the user types the data via whatsapp. With the menus working, but I'm not able to do submenus.

Comment: "A library that connects via whatstapp" isn't specific enough. How do you expect anyone to be able to help if they don't even know what library you're trying to use?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the question was more about python. The library name is macbot.

Comment: Every human interface library has a different way of handling menus and submenus, so answering "how to do them?" questions requires know that bit of information (unless you're getting a `SyntaxError` or some other generic problem).

Comment: Okay. Do you have any suggestions on how to do them?

Comment: No, never heard of it (and couldn't find it). Is there documentation? Where is it located?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **regex** or '**in**' keyword, ex : if "1" in message.command:
but i will prefer using regex so it will be more specified that what user types is a command or not.

also if you like to compress your files(because i am having like 30+menu in my bot) you will probably like to keep them in seperate file, so you can use this interface file '**yowsup.layers.interface**' which contains '**YowInterfaceLayer, ProtocolEntityCallback**'.

**"^fun$"** this regex will detect the word fun and **"^wiki (?P[^$]+)$"** will detect the word after the keyword wiki so it have far more control over commands.